# Different THREE.JS 3D models as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, three.js

I want to make each of the objects open a new page using a URL. For example, clicking on about me will open an about me page. I cannot get it to work. What am I missing or doing wrong? Here is my click event for the objects. I can share more code if this is not enough.

```
    function onClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    let objects = [aboutme, skills, interests, projects, contact];

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);


    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        console.log('Intersection:', intersects[0].objects); //this works
        window.open(intersects[0].objects);
    }}
```

If I write the code like this,

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
            console.log('Intersection:', intersects[0].objects);
            window.open('https://www.google.com',intersects[0].objects);
        }
```

It works but clicking on all models opens up the same google website.

Comment: surely it's because you're passing the url for google as the first param as to why it's opening google...

Answer (score 1):

`intersects[0].objects` does not exist. Based [on the Raycaster docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject), my guess is you're trying to pass `intersects[0].object`, to the `window.open()` function, but that second argument is [expecting a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), not a 3D Mesh object.

Not sure how you're expecting different behaviors when you call the exact same thing:

`window.open('https://www.google.com', "[object Object]");`

multiple times. Maybe you'd like to [assign a name to each object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.name), and then use that by accessing `intersects[0].object.name`?